# Name or tag for kana phrase videos

Tags: japanese-language, terminology, amv

I'd like to know the Japanese name or tag of a type of video that used to be popular on Nico Nico Douga on 2007-2010 (maybe there are still some people making these videos but I can't find them anymore).

In these videos the creator would take a character from an anime and then put a phrase/scene from that character for each hiragana/kana syllable.

For example for Kagami from Lucky star (this is the video I remember):

- あ(a) - Anta no tame janai.
- え(e) - Eeeeto.
- い(i) - Imi ga wakaranai.

I remember that there were many videos for many characters and anime but many of them were deleted and I can't find the videos I had favorited.

Answer (score 2):

I found the video: http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm2931268

The tags I was looking for are: ツッコミカルタ and アニメかるたリンク